# Access the cookie file and upload it in the selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I'm working in automating a website, I want to access the cookie file(I wanna know the cookie will be stored in my PC, can i access it) and upload the cookie file at the start of my webdriver, is that possible can anyone help me on this.

Thanks.